# Are there other national leagues with other country teams?

Tags: major-leagues

The MLS, NBA, MLB and NHL are considered mostly as USA leagues but they have teams from Canada. Are there other national leagues (any sport) that are mostly from one country but have teams from other nations?

Comment: Moderator note: [Stack Exchange generally frowns on "list" type questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question). I think this one might just about have small enough scope that it can survive - to that aim, I've created a [community wiki answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/22838/6126) that anyone can edit. Please add more examples to that answer rather than creating your own unless you really feel that it would be important to create your own answer. I will be somewhat harsh in deleting new answers that could be part of the wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The North American examples certainly aren't unique.

- Monaco has teams in the French systems for various sports, including both [football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AS_Monaco_FC) (Ligue 1) and [volleyball](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_sportive_de_Monaco_(volley-ball)).
- A number of examples in the UK football systems:

  - The Welsh [Cardiff City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiff_City_F.C.), [Swansea City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swansea_City_A.F.C.) and [Wrexham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrexham_A.F.C.) play in the English system.
  - The English [Berwick Rangers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berwick_Rangers_F.C.) play in the Scottish system.
  - [The New Saints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Saints_F.C.), who represent both [Llansantffraid-ym-Mechain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llansantffraid-ym-Mechain) in Wales and the much larger [Oswestry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oswestry) in England, play in the Welsh system.
  - The Northern Irish [Derry City FC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derry_City_F.C.) play in the Republic of Ireland system.
- [Kontinental Hockey League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontinental_Hockey_League) has teams mostly from Russia (19 in the last season) but also from Belarus, China, Finland, Kazakhstan and Latvia (1 from each in the last season).
- [Erste Liga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erste_Liga_(ice_hockey)) (formerly MOL liga) is an ice-hockey liga with teams from Hungary, Romania, Austria. (And in the past there was also one team from Slovakia and one team from Serbia.)
- Since the 2018-19 season, some Hungarian teams play in [Tipsport liga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipsport_liga_(hockey)) - Slovak ice hockey league.
- [San Marino Calcio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Marino_Calcio) plays in Italian football system.
- New Zealand has teams in a range of Australian sports leagues: [Warriors in the NRL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand_Warriors), [Breakers in the NBL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand_Breakers), [Phoenix in the A-League](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wellington_Phoenix_FC), and various previous conjoint rugby, cricket and netball competitions.
- Andorran teams play in Spanish leagues, mostly lower level leagues. However, in basketball, [BC Andorra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BC_Andorra) plays in the [Liga ACB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liga_ACB).
- Liechtenstein does not have a Football League on its own. All Liechtenstein clubs participate in [Swiss Leagues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_in_Liechtenstein).
- Teams from both Estonia and Latvia play in [Baltic Men Volleyball League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltic_Men_Volleyball_League).

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that the Estonia-Latvia volleyball league can be called "teams from one country playing in the competition of another country". It appears that league is deliberately designs to be binational, not uninational with additions from elsewhere.